# Session sharing across WARs

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, tomcat, war

In our application we have 2 different war files deployed in same tomcat. In our case we are storing some attributes in session which are required by both WARs, for which we should be able to access the session of one context (one war ) from other context (other war).

To achive this we have enabled cross context in tomcat and sharing the session by storing them in a map in each context. But this approach is became complex and cumbersome so that session management became very hard. And moreover if we opt for Tomcat clustering then this approach was failing.

So can any one suggest a better way to share session across multiple applications deployed in single tomcat or multiple tomcat nodes

Comment: It is not recommend to share HttpSession; but you can share other objects. For example, you can register an object via JNDI and access the same object in all your apps (databases use this to pool connections).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple webservice to store session related information.

Like when one session is created on Login on APP1, that information will be stored on the webservice which will held the information till APP1 is logged out.

And same information will be accessible to the APP2 till APP1 session is there.

Webservice can be a simple REST API, which will contain info in JSON format.